# Can I rely on this argument reference behaviour, cross-platform?

Tags: javascript, scope, reference, arguments

The following code returns `bar` in major browsers, but how long has this been the case? The last example (zoo returning `100`) on the [MDN arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) page doesn't indicate a time this feature was introduced.

```
(function(v){
  (function(a){
    a[0] = 'bar';
  })(arguments);
  return v;
})('foo');
```

This is just an example but my aim is to have one function that can consistently normalise arguments of many other, related functions to avoid repeated code.

Comment: Everything in this code is fundamental to JS. So it behaves as it should as per current standard. (but it does not mean one should write such code)

Comment: and has so for a "while", but before you get all gung ho on this, there are lots of pitfalls.  For example, read: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/04/10/javascript-don-t-reassign-your-function-arguments/

Comment: Can't use this pattern anyway because these references don't exist where arguments are omitted: `(function(v, w){arguments[1]='bar';return w})('foo')` returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I rely on this argument reference behaviour, cross-platform?

You can for every browser that complies with the modern standard:

> An arguments exotic object is an exotic object whose array index properties map to the formal parameters bindings of an invocation of its associated ECMAScript function.

It was not the case in the ES5.1 that mentioned that values should have been copied during the [`CreateArgumentsObject` process](https://es5.github.io/#x10.6)

References

- [9.4.4 Arguments Exotic Objects](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arguments-exotic-objects)

Comment: That's the 2015 spec, but you at least lead me to the [1st ECMAScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%201st%20edition,%20June%201997.pdf), where the last dot-point of section 10.1.8 seems to agree.

Comment: @Walf oh, you're concerned about digging *that* far. I've never read something much older than ES3. Btw, it's interesting how the referred 1st edition is written with "easier to get" (more closer to the natural) language.

Comment: Not really, but it was easiest to look at the first item in the list. Indeed.